# Terraform version issue while using terraform plan

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

Note:- The code was written in Terraform v0.11.13 and i pulled it in my local and i made changes according to my local terraform version which is Terraform v0.11.14. Now while terraform plan i am getting (Error:
Terraform doesn't allow running any operations against a state
that was written by a future Terraform version. The state is
reporting it is written by Terraform '0.11.14')
Please run at least that version of Terraform to continue.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a new install from the scratch (*If you didn't run `terraform apply` before*) you can delete `terraform.tfstate` file and run `terraform init` before `terraform plan`.

It will create a new `terraform.tfstate` file and you will get the opportunity run `terraform plan`

If you made `terraform apply` before you can do a dirty hack, just open `terraform.tfstate` file and change the version of the terraform. And then it allows you run `terraform plan` without any errors

Answer (score 0):

You will have to update the terraform version in statefile. Check the version in statefile `terraform.tfstate`, switch to the same version either using ``tfenv`or`tfswitch`to switch between version. Once, you confirm the version then try`terraform plan` again and see the output